# Local Council needs recording device for barking dog matter

Tags: audio, recording, outdoor

I have been tasked with finding options for our government council to purchase an outdoor recording device we can possibly attach to a fence, post, car or tree to monitor some of our VIP Nuisance barking complaint matters. These types of complaints between nieghbours are quite frequent and cause a substantial impact to residents and also a drain to council resources.

Can anyone recommend where to start in terms of searching for a suitable recorder or what devices you think may be suitable for all weather outdoor recording that would pick up barking noise at least 15-30 metres away during night time hours.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Song Meter if you have somewhere safe to mount it:

http://www.wildlifeacoustics.com/products/song-meter-sm2-birds

Usually used for wildlife recording. I expect it would pick up at that range, but you would not be able to measure loudness levels or anything that detailed.